# Extract name of file which triggered processing from DStream

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using `textFileStream` to process files coming to the directory. Is it possible to extract the name of the file, which triggered processing?

For example, when file **2019-04-18_very_important.txt** comes to the directory I listen to I would like to be able to extract the name of that file.

```
context
    .textFileStream("/path/to/directory")
    .transform(rdd -> /** How can I get '2019-04-18_very_important.txt' here? **/)
...
```

Comment: Take a look on this link: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/107820/keeping-track-of-filenames-with-spark-streaming.html

Comment: Can you use the newer structured streams API instead? If yes, it has this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#input_file_name--

Comment: Unfortunately, I use an older version of spark without structured streaming.